# Multiplication of value of each postition of String?

Tags: c++

I have this string `str` . I want to Multiply value of each position of string with `7` or any value. First I used string Function `str.at()` and stored in a new `char` type variable, but when i multiplied the index `0` value: `9` with `7` it's giving me `399` instead of `63`. I have also tried this without a string function, like this: `char s = str[0];` and then multiplied `s` with `7` but i'm still not getting the correct answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "9958721";
    char s = str[0];
    cout << s * 7;

    cout << "\nPROGRAM ENDED...";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recall that `9 != '9'`. Add `cout << s * 1;`, it might prove illuminating.

Comment: See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: you're multiplying `57 * 7` where `57` is the ascii value of character `9`

Comment: So, how do i multiply the value instead of ASCII value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `'9'` ASCII code is 57. [See](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/number-nine-ascii-code-57.html#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20letter%2C%20character,%229%22%20in%20ASCII%20table.)

To get the expected result use something like the following

```
string str = "9958721";
char s = str[0];
cout << 7 * (static_cast<int>(s) - static_cast<int>('0'));
```

to subtract the equivalent ASCII value of zero. Note that they are ordered.

And see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)